# Alert when dynamic button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get an alert to trigger when a dynamically generated button is clicked?

The alert is not going to be the final function but was a test to make sure the trigger is working correctly.

I tried a "onclick" function as a trigger and used the id as a jQuery trigger so not sure why it would not work; I will add a snippet below that shows what I mean.

From the file that generates and displays the button (it displays OK):

```
var modOptsMsg = document.getElementById("modOptionsMessage").value + '<input type="button" id="removePost" onclick="removePost()" value="Remove Post"/>';

$("#modOptsShowMsg").empty().append(modOptsMsg);
```

Neither of these simple tests work in JS or jQuery:

```
function removePost(){
    alert("alert");
}
$('#removePost').click(function(){
    alert("alert");
});
```

Comment: Before question is closed as duplicate: it should be `$(document).on("click", '#removePost', function() { alert("alert"); });`

Comment: @regent thank you! i knew i had just been looking at it to long and as for duplicate i only posted it once?

Comment: @Parody you're welcome. You asked once. But this question is asked by different people many times per each day :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard should pick appropriate duplicate that isn't 4 years old and predates `on()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Regent has pointed out in the comments, use:

```
$(document).on("click", '#removePost', function() { 
    alert("alert"); 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  $('#modOptsShowMsg').on("click", '#removePost', function() { 
   alert("alert"); 
});
```

the above code will work..if jquery is lesser than 1.7 use .live() instead of .on()

Comment: this won't delegate event and assumes that element exists when code is run. IS no different than using `click()` which is simply a shortand for `on('click'..`

Comment: yup.. it is a miss, now edited.